# Deleting _vti folders programmatically

Tags: frontpage

Is there a way I can delete the _vti folders programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can delete _vti folders programmatically.  These are the findings

- Make sure your application does not use MS front page or SharePoint
- Manually delete the folders/files
- Goto Add/Remove windows components-> IIS -> and uncheck the FrontPage Server 
  Extensions    check box

the _vti folders are not regenerated again.